# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'calendar' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar

Quiero crear un evento en javascript para insertar un evento en Google Calendar con el siguiente código :

```
var event = {
  'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2018-03-7T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'Europe/Madrid'
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2018-03-7T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'Europe/Madrid'
  },
  'recurrence': [
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ],
  'attendees': [
    {'email': 'lpage@example.com'},
    {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'}
  ],
  'reminders': {
    'useDefault': false,
    'overrides': [
      {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
      {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10}
    ]
  }
};

var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
  'calendarId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com',
  'resource': event
});

request.execute(function(event) {
  appendPre('Event created: ' + event.htmlLink);
});
```

pero me da el siguiente error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'calendar' of undefined

Creo que es porque no estoy autorizado en el Auth2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente el error ocurre en la línea

```
var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
  'calendarId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com',
  'resource': event
});
```

y ello porque seguramente no has cargado la librería de Google API para JavaScript. La guía de cómo empezar con dicha librería se encuentra en inglés en https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

La guía da tres opciones

1. Cargar el "API discovery document" y luego ensamblar la solicitud.
2. Usar gapi.client.request
3. Usar CORS